# Zend Mail 1.12 setReturnPath

Tags: email, zend-framework, frameworks, path, return

When i set the Return Path with setReturnPath, the e-mail header of the generated e-mail is different from the SET value (info@test.com). Is this an issue of Zend Framework 1.12.3?
Or can i fix it with another setting / header?

```
$mail = new Zend_Mail();
$mail->setBodyHtml($html);
$mail->setReplyTo('info@test.com');
$mail->setReturnPath('noreply@test.com');
$mail->setFrom('info@test.com', '...');
$mail->addTo(...);
$mail->setSubject(...);
$mail->send();
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about the order of the code. 
This code is untested my or my not work.

```
//Create Zend_Mail object.
$MailObj = new Zend_Mail();
$message= "<h1>Welcome to the example</h1><br>" .
           "<p>An example email.</p>";
//Initialize parameters.

$fromEmail = "FROM_EMAIL_ADDRESS";
$fromFullName = "FROM_FULL_NAME";
$to = "YOUR_EMAIL_HERE";
$subject = "This is an example";

$MailObj->setBodyHtml($message);
$MailObj->setFrom($fromEmail, $fromFullName);
$MailObj->addTo($to);
$MailObj->setSubject($subject);
$MailObj->setReplyTo('info@test.com');
$MailObj->setReturnPath('noreply@test.com');
```